# How to increase the memory available to your python program in Pycharm Memory Error

Tags: python, memory, pycharm

I am trying to read around 20k+ text files but I run out of memory before I can process them.
How can I increase the available memory for my python script? in Pycharm. I have already tried increasing my heap memory for Pycharm by going to help->change memory settings but it didn't work. Also if I run my script in Jupyter it works perfectly fine just getting this issue in Pycharm.

Comment: Do you need to read all of the files into memory before processing them?

Comment: Not sure it's a pycharm issue, can you try executing your script directly using the CLI?

Comment: yes I need to extract all of the words from these files